# What exactly is AVCHD?

Tags: file-formats

Is it a codec? I don't think so; I believe it uses MPEG4/H.264 for video and AC3 for audio.

Is it a container format? Doesn't seem to make a huge amount of sense; there are enough out there already and it's likely that a suitable one already exists.

Is it simply a specification that specifies a particular combination of pre-existing technologies? But this would imply that AVCHD files could also be called something else, like "MPEG4 container with H264/AC3 inside".

So what exactly does AVCHD mean?

Comment: This question seems more broadcast and compression specific than AV Production! Inviting experts to a new site proposal [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) which aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this image from Wikipedia says it best:

[image]

AVCHD is **not a codec**, but it is also **not just a container**.

Just like "every other" container, AVCHD features:

- Video streams
- Audio streams
- Subtitles

But in addition, for example:

- Playlists
- Menu presentation (like in a DVD)

> Is it simply a specification that specifies a particular combination of pre-existing technologies?

Yes.

> But this would imply that AVCHD files could also be called something else, like "MPEG4 container with H264/AC3 inside".

But who would like to call it that? Several other specifications take already existing specifications, remix them, and they aren't called "Open Source Container format for XYZ".

I think it's a "one format fits it all" mentality, which is why you'll find AVCHD on many consumer devices.

Answer (score -5):

AVCHD is basically just a consumer name for H.264, which in turn is another name for the ISO standard MPEG-4, Layer 10. It is one of the most significant steps forward in video encoding in recent times.

To the very best of my knowledge, it is a codec since it is used to encode and decode video but it is also a specification.

Comment: That is completely wrong. AVCHD is a wrapper that uses h.264 multiplexed into an MPEG Transport Stream. The confusion might stem from the fact that MPEG-4 Part 10 is also called AVC. But AVC and AVCHD have nothing in common. see the [Format Specification](http://www.avchd-info.org/format/index.html).